# Image Path Space Issue - Php Array

Tags: php, arrays, string, space

I don't know where the issue in my code.

There is a space automatically added to the image name after i get the value from array.

i have tried with `str_replace` too. but that space still shows in output.

here it is my code

```
<?php
$domain='localhost/test';

$id=5;

$animal = array("alligator.jpg", "
ant.jpg", "
bear.jpg", "
bee.jpg", "
butterfly.jpg", "
cat.jpg", "
camel.jpg", "
cheetah.jpg", "
cockroach.jpg", "
cow.jpg", "
crow.jpg", "
deer.jpg");

$imageName=$animal[$id];
$imageName2=str_replace(" ","",$imageName);

echo "$domain/img/$imageName";
echo "<br /><br />$domain/img/$imageName2";

?>
```

current output: `localhost/test/img/ cat.jpg`  -> space added before the cat name

expected output: `localhost/test/img/cat.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$imageName2=trim($imageName`);

use this

or

```
$imageName2= preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $imageName);
```